# Celery - Assign task name to a task in a group

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am celery groups along with concurrency to execute tasks in parallel

```
for item in response_json:
    job_list.append(some_task.s(item))

job = group(job_list)
result = job.apply_async(queue="queue1")
```

However, I would like to assign custom task names to each item task so that the task can be revoked later. I want to revoke only a single task inside the group and not the entire group.

I know I can assign `task_name` if I use `apply_async()` but that would apply to the whole group and not a single task.

Is there anyway I can assign `task_name` to each task inside a group?

Comment: You can always revoke task by its ID. So just keep task IDs and you will be fine.

Comment: Is there a way to get the task id when using a celery group?

Comment: A single task's result is represented by AsyncResult, while group result is represented by GroupResult. There you will find all the details about tasks created in particular group.